# How to kill all the threads which they are not the main thread?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, objective-c-blocks, core-foundation

I do many asynchronous execution with blocks in my application.

But I need to kill all the threads which they are not the main thread if a certain event appears in my application.

So is it possible to stop the execution of all blocks ? Or in other terms, kill all the threads which they are not the main thread ?

PS : I tried to execute blocks inside NSOperationQueue, but my first operation does not start at the good time while the followings does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to kill threads to cancel operations, you’re probably doing it wrong. `NSOperationQueue` or similar solution (like implementing cancellation logic in your blocks) is IMHO the right way to go. If you have some problems with the operation queue, try to sort it out, don’t avoid the problem by creating a worse one.

Comment: My view displays pictures, and I begin by loading their thumbnails and asynchronously, I charge the real picture and as soon as it is loaded, it is displayed instead of the thumbnail.
But if the user has an heavy photo which it loads in background and if he swipe to next photo, the previous heavy photo is continuing loading in background, and if the new photo is slight, the loading of the heavy photo ends after, and it supersedes the new photo on the view. So, in my code, I tried to stop all the backgrounds threads when the user swipe to next photo. That's my problem.

Comment: That’s a classic use case that doesn’t need killing any threads. I suggest that you implement the image loading as a cancellable `NSOperation` and cancel image loading when the image is no longer needed.